How to come back to Home page on tap in flutter
This is my bottom navigation bar setup
 List<String> labels = ['Home', 'Cart', 'Notification', 'Account'];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return PopScope(
     canPop: false,
     onPopInvoked: ((didPop) {
         if (selctedIndex != 0) {
           setState(() {
             selctedIndex = 0;
           });
         } else{
             final now = DateTime.now();
           if(currentPress == null || now.difference(currentPress!) > const Duration(seconds: 2)){
             currentPress = now;
             ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
               SnackBar(
                 elevation: 1,
                 behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                 backgroundColor:  Colors.black,
                 content: const Text('Double Press to exit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                 duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
               ),
             );
           } else {
             SystemNavigator.pop();
           }
         }
     }),
     child: Scaffold(
       body: items[selctedIndex],
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
         type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
         currentIndex: selctedIndex,
         selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
           fontSize: 12,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
           color: Colors.black
         ),
         elevation: 3,
         items: List.generate(items.length, (index) {
           return BottomNavigationBarItem(
             icon: CustomIcon(
               icon: icons[index],
               isSelected: index == selctedIndex,
             ),
             label: labels[index],
           );
         }),
         onTap: (value) {
           setState(() {
              selctedIndex = value;
           });
         },
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

This is my home screen sample part
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool isExit = false;
  bool categorySelected = false;
  String categoryTitle ='';
  CartItems categoryProduct = items[0];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return PopScope(
      canPop: (categorySelected || isExit) ? false : true,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        setState(() {
          categorySelected = false;
          isExit = false;
        });
      },
      child: categorySelected
      ? CategoryProductsScreen(title: categoryTitle, items: categoryProduct)
      : Scaffold(
        appBar: homeAppBar(
          icon: CupertinoIcons.square_stack_3d_down_dottedline,
          navigate: (){
            // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomBar(index: 3),));
         }
        ),
        // other widgets goes here
       )
      )
     )
    }
   }

I have a trouble here I need one thing If I tap the Home screen from other screens of the bottom bar it comes correctly move to the home screen but In my home screen I show the category products to the home screen body when it called. On that context If I press the home screen it didn't come to the default home screen. how to I set this
